scripts fail to import
I am trying to add the web3 script to my page (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/getting-started.html), but in no way does it work.
To add it in VS code so I get the IntelliSense that's basically the only code that works,
import Web3 from 'web3';
the problem is that if I use it, I get a bunch of errors in the console...
TypeError: The specifier “web3” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything.
Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

I get as well this thing,
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> web3.ts:18
lockdown-install.js:1:97687

import Web3 from './node_modules/web3/src/index.js'

If I specify the path manually then I get
Script from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/web3/lib/commonjs/web3.d.ts” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“video/mp2t”). Index.html

If I try to use type=text/javascript or typescript, then I get the error the following error ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️
import definition must be defined at the top of the page

All the solutions I found at best fix 1 problem, but then the new one appears so in the end nothing got fixed, i am using vs code, and to run the server I use Live server plugin, i did install all the npm required modules, but it fixed NOTHING, what to do then?
